# javascript Regex trim up to 'space' AND 'dash' or match

Tags: javascript, regex, match, trim

I asked a similar question before and got the correct response.  This time though I would rather try and get two variables for the name after the 'By' and the 'Date' separately.

The problem with the below match is that it isn't picking up if the name has a space or a dash in it:

```
<p class="review-rating">
 By carolyn.fleetwood
 - Feb 11, 2012
 -
 Something.com
</p>
<p class="review-rating">
 By Dont-work
 - Feb 11, 2012
 -
 Something.com
</p>
<p class="review-rating">
 By wont work
 - Feb 11, 2012
 -
 Something.com
</p>

$('.review-rating').each(function() {
    var matches = $(this).text().match(/\s*By\s+([\w.]+)\s*-\s*([\w, ]+)/);
    alert("Date: " + matches[2] + " | By: " + matches[1]);
});​
```

With the above it wont pick up the dash or spaces after the "By ".

See here jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GYSbR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the line is their name, just switch from `[\w.]` to `[^\r\n]+` so it catches the rest of the content(s) up until the next new line.

Comment: I knew it was something simple, thank you.  Was looking for the "up to next line", this did it.

Comment: Another hiccup.  Is there a way to return NULL or zero or anything for the name if the word "By" isn't there?  I just want to pull the date if the word "By" isn't there (aka match[2]) if it doesn't contain "By"?

Comment: Wrap it in a group? `(?:By\s+)?` Then it tries to match `By\s+` if it's there, otherwise ignores it.

Comment: I noticed this puts the date field in the match[1] now see here: http://jsfiddle.net/GYSbR/25/

Comment: Change the group a bit to include the match: `(?:By\s+([^\r\n]+)|.*?)` This will give you a name or `undefined`. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably just to use the dot matcher: this matches everything except new lines in the default case.

```
.match(/\s*By\s+(.+)\s*-\s*([\w, ]+)/)
```

The only caveat is that it might capture some trailing whitespace on the "By" line if there is any. One way around that:

```
.match(/\s*By\s+(.*\S)\s*-\s*([\w, ]+)/)
```

Here `.*\S` roughly translates to "match one or more characters which ends with non-whitespace, no new lines".